# Как настроить SimpleDNS Plus 6 для работы с доменами и ip

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, dns, iis, ns

Есть программа SimpleDNS Plus 6. Есть некий домен, пусть это будет `mysite.com`. Есть ip-адрес, пусть будет `192.168.3.21` (это публичный, не локальный). И требуется чтобы **клиент, не я,** по переходу на `mysite.com` выводился ресурс, который находится на `192.168.3.21`. И собственно вопрос...

**Как это сделать, имея данную программу?**
И еще, если кто-то занимался windows IIS, то как можно организовать привязку домена к определенному сайту?

*В качестве сервера windows 8.1.
Также есть панель управления SolidCp (что-то наподобии Cpanel, только для windows).Физический доступ к серверу имею.*

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDNS Plus 6 для данной задачи это как из пушки по воробьям. Может, Вас устроит решение попроще?

На той машине, откуда будете открывать сайт в браузере, открыть `Notepad` в сессии с повышенными привилегиями - клик правой кнопкой на иконке, выбрать "Запустить от имени Администратора".

В Notepad открыть файл `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Прописать строку:

```
192.168.3.21 mysite.com
```

Сохранить файл.

---

Насчет IIS - вот [отличная статья](http://pyatilistnik.org/creating-an-iis-site-in-windows-server-2012-r2/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы чуток не поняли мой вопрос. Правку я уже в вопросе сделал. А за статейку IIS спасибо.

Comment: я же не буду бегать к клиентам и просить в hosts сделать поправку

Comment: @Egor, то есть Вы хотите поднять свой собственный DNS сервер ради одного сайта? Не проще ли будет для начала использовать публичный бесплатный DNS сервер, как, например, [he.net](https://dns.he.net/)? И для правильной работы DNS сервера он должен быть прописан как NX запись в домене через регистратора. Есть у Вас доступ?

Comment: Доступ у меня есть, но решение с https://dns.he.net/ мне нравиться больше. Спасибо вам